# Windows 10 mobile UWP - slow back button

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone, win-universal-app

I have simply application written in c#, with sqlite database. I realized that it's not working fast on my phone. I'm pretty sure that problem is linked with functionality of pressed bulit-in back button. When I repeat several time this process:

Open new page -> return to previous page by back button, the application starting slows down.

When I added my own back button only to test, everything works fine.

I base mostly on this article:
http://www.wintellect.com/devcenter/jprosise/handling-the-back-button-in-windows-10-uwp-apps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Open new page -> return to previous page by back button, the application starting slows down.

After looking into your project, I found out the problem: You are registering `SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested +=OnBackRequested` on every page. `SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested` **is an application scope event.** It won't dispose the eventhandler when you are navigating between pages. You only need to register it once in your whole application.

So, to fix the problem, you can comment out all the `BackRequested` event registration of your pages's code-behind and keep only the one in your `App.xaml.cs`.

For example: in `ProductsPage.xaml.cs` comment out or delete following lines:

```
//SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested += (s, e) =>
//{
//    // TODO: Go back to the previous page
//    Frame.Navigate(typeof(main1));
//};
```

Answer (score 0):

If your back is Phone hard key you may handle the event.

The link is say the pc and add the back button and you should

```
SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested +=OnBackRequested;

    private void OnBackRequested(object sender, BackRequestedEventArgs e)
    {
        Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;


        if (rootFrame?.CanGoBack==true)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            rootFrame.GoBack();
        }
        else
        {
            Application.Current.Exit();
        }
    }
}
```

http://edi.wang/post/2016/2/1/windows-10-uwp-back-button-tricks
http://blog.csdn.net/lindexi_gd/article/details/50618029

Comment: so I did, it's the same way on my article. I send my whole project with databasE (vs 2015). 

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5ZmP3NVyVJkQnBPRDBHSmdtUFU/view?usp=sharing

P.S Please don't scare up of quality of my code:)

Comment: can I send You by email?

Comment: [mail](mailto:lindexi_gd@163.com)

Comment: you can `if (rootFrame?.CanGoBack==true)`